# How to list inspections in IntelliJ that exactly match those highlighted in open files?

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings

The open files in IntelliJ IDEA highlight warnings due to code inspections (eg. when an argument might be null).  I want to be able to list all of these inspections in one place, eg. just for changed files.  If I do

Analyze -> Inspect Code (with a custom scope of Changed Files)

then I get all these warnings and more.  I only want to see the warnings I see highlighted in the file, not other inspections.

Perhaps I just have to disable all other inspections not shown as highlights (perhaps in another profile), but I was hoping there was another way?

Answer (score 0):

Profiles are used in both cases.

You have to make sure the profile chosen in File->Settings... ->Editor->Inspections->Profile is the same profile that you use for your "Inspect Code"-run (Analyze->Inspect Code... ->Inspection profile).

Comment: I've checked that they do indeed match ("Project Default") though I think the issue is that some inspections have "(available for Analyze|Inspect Code)" written next to them, so perhaps these are the ones that are not shown as highlights that I would need to remove from the profile used for the Inspect menu option to get the same results as highlights?

Comment: You are right of course. Sorry. 
Those seem to be global inspections, that are hard to do on a single open file without taking too many resources.
I think you would actually get the desired behaviour by removing all of them as you proposed.
I would atleast keep them in a separate profile for future use though. Some of them sound very reasonable and useful.

Comment: Even creating a profile matching the Project Default minus "Available for Analyze|Inspect" seems not to work.  For example, I have "Unused Declaration" in my custom profile, but the results of the Inspect Code do not match the open file analysis.  There is something that is found to be unused according to the former where the latter shows a green tick.  Of course it's useful to find this extra issue, but I would rather just have exactly the file analysis issues in one place.